# Remove Command Buttons in Gridview when adding an empty row

Tags: c#, gridview

I am having a problem merging the column that includes an 'edit' and 'delete' button of a gridview when the data row is empty.
When there is no data in the dataTable, I add an empty row to the dataTable so that the footer will display that includes the add button.
If I don't try to merge the columns in the empty row, it is fine.  But I would like to remove the 'edit' and delete' buttons when this row is empty or at least disable them.

This is the code when the user selects a course from a dropdown that contains no sections:

```
 protected void ddlCourses_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get CourseId
        int tiCourseID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCourses.SelectedValue.ToString());

        SectionGridView.DataSource = CSectionInfo.getDataUsingCourseID(tiCourseID);
        SectionGridView.DataBind();

        if (CSectionInfo.CurrentSectionCount == 0)
        {
            SectionGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = SectionGridView.Columns.Count;        
            SectionGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;        
            SectionGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Section Data was found for this Course";
        }
    }
```

This is the gridview with contains the 'edit and delete buttons:

```
 <asp:Content runat="server" ID="SectionContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="SectionContent">
<section class="section">
<div class="content-wrapper">
<asp:Label ID="lblSelectCourse" runat="server" Text="Select Course: " CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCourses" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Height="25px" Width="180px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCourses_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
<br />
<br />
<asp:GridView ID="SectionGridView" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Caption="Section Information" CaptionAlign="Top" 
    CssClass="grid" HorizontalAlign="Left" ShowFooter="True" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="4" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" 
    OnPageIndexChanging="SectionGridView_PageIndexChanging">
    <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SectionID" SortExpression="cgvSectionID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="sgvLblSectionID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SectionID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CourseID" SortExpression="sgvCourseID">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="sgvDdlCourseID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CourseID") %>'></asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="sgvLblCourseID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CourseID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
             <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="sgvInsertCourseID" runat="server" Width="90%"></asp:DropDownList>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="sgvName">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="sgvEditName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="sgvLblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="sgvInsertName" runat="server" Width="90%"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle ForeColor="Black" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SKU" SortExpression="sgvSKU">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="sgvEditSKU" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SKU") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="sgvLblSKU" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SKU") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="sgvInsertSKU" runat="server" Width="90%"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle ForeColor="Black" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Registration Open Date" SortExpression="sgvRegOpenDate">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="sgvEditRegOpenDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RegistrationOpen", "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="sgvLblRegOpenDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RegistrationOpen", "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="sgvInsertRegOpenDate" runat="server" Width="90%"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle ForeColor="Black" />
        </asp:TemplateField>

         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Registration Close Date" SortExpression="sgvRegCloseDate">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="sgvEditRegCloseDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RegistrationClose", "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="sgvLblRegCloseDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RegistrationClose", "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="sgvInsertRegCloseDate" runat="server" Width="90%"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle ForeColor="Black" />
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Section Start Date" SortExpression="sgvSecStartDate">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="sgvEditSecStartDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SectionStart", "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="sgvLblSecStartDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SectionStart", "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="sgvInsertSecStartDate" runat="server" Width="90%"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle ForeColor="Black" />
        </asp:TemplateField>

         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Section End Date" SortExpression="sgvSecEndDate">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="sgvEditSecEndDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SectionEnd", "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="sgvLblSecEndDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SectionEnd", "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="sgvInsertSecEndDate" runat="server" Width="90%"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle ForeColor="Black" />
        </asp:TemplateField>

         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Member Price" SortExpression="sgvMemberPrice">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="sgvEditMemberPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MemberPrice", "{0:C}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="sgvLblMemberPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MemberPrice", "{0:C}") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="sgvInsertMemberPrice" runat="server" Width="90%"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle ForeColor="Black" />
        </asp:TemplateField>

         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Non-member Price" SortExpression="sgvNonMemberPrice">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="sgvEditNonMemberPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NonMemberPrice", "{0:C}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="sgvLblNonMemberPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NonMemberPrice", "{0:C}") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="sgvInsertNonMemberPrice" runat="server" Width="90%"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle ForeColor="Black" />
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ShowHeader="False">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="sgvImgUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="sgvImgCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="sgvEditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="sgvDeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="sgvBtnAdd" runat="server" CommandName="Add" Text="Add Section" Width="90%" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

How do I remove the Delete and Edit LinkButtons when the datarow is empty?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use 'EmptyDataTemplate' to add an merged column row with the text 'No data for this section' and a second row with all of the controls from the footer template to allow insertion of data.